# Finding marginal pdf - solved but unsure

Tags: probability

I'm given an equation
$$ f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = \{k \ \ \ \ \ (x,y) \in T, \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ otherwise.$$
where $$ T = \{(x,y) : x > 0, y > 0, x + y < 9\} $$

I have calculated $k$ being $\frac{2}{81}$ and I'm trying to find margical pdf of Y.
So I did
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\ dx = \int_0^9k \ dx$$
$$ [kx]_0^9 = 9k$$
and make
$$ f_Y(y) = \{9k, \ \ \ \ 0 < y < 9, \ 0 \ \ \ \ otherwise. $$

I'm quite confused as of if I have done this correctly or am I completely off track. And how do I check if this is a probability density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the support of the joint distribution is $x, y \gt 0, x + y \lt 9$

So, $ \displaystyle f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx = \int_0^{9-y} \frac{2}{81} \ dx$

$ \displaystyle f_Y(y) = \frac{2 (9-y)}{81}, ~0 \lt y \lt 9$